# Docker container: mount plugged devices on Windows

Tags: windows, docker, mount

Running a container on Linux:

```
$ docker run -it --name damastes --rm --mount type=bind,source="$HOME"/,target=/enjoy --mount type=bind,source=/run/media,target=/run/media,bind-propagation=shared -w /enjoy damastes:latest
```

`docker-compose.yml`:

```
services:
  damastes:
    image: damastes:latest
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: $HOME
        target: /enjoy
      - type: bind
        source: /run/media
        target: /run/media
        bind:
          propagation: shared
    working_dir: /enjoy
```

Can't even start to guess how the second mount should look on Windows.